# Delphi Prism: How to load Winform without showing it?

Tags: winforms, delphi, controls, delphi-prism, showdialog

I have a winform that needs to be loaded to update its controls' values or properties, before it is to be shown.

I found a stackoverflow question asking the same thing, but it's answer doesn't really help me. [Load a form without showing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921/load-a-form-without-showing-it)

Any sample code will be appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the form like this:

```
form := new MyForm();
```

Assuming you have implemented a method on `MyForm` to update the values, call it:

```
form.Update();//may need to pass parameters here
```

Show the form in the usual way:

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3):

Only you need create a new instance of the form and set the values of the controls.

check this code

```
Var
  AForm : ChildForm;
begin
  AForm:= new ChildForm;
  AForm.textBox1.Text:='Foo';  //this control can be accessed here  because the Modifiers property was set to public. 


  AForm.Show;
end;
```

Btw remember if you want modify or access the controls of another form you must set the property `Modifiers` of the control to access to `public`.

Comment: RRUZ your answer and David Heffernan answers both works great. I wasn't sure how to choose between the two of you. So, I closed my eyes and spun my mouse and it stopped on David's answer. Sorry..:)

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> **Form.Load**
>   Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

So you can do all updates to the controls that are necessary before you show the form in this event handler.

But actually it is probably better to use [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on the controls, so that they automatically reflect the current values you want them to show and you don't have to write any glue code bringing data on controls (and reading from them).