# How to show a form without "showing" it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have winforms application which has a popup dialog. I need the dialog to popup but without showing itself. This is how I currently do it:

```
DialogForm myDialog = new DialogForm();
myDialog.Show();
myDialog.Visible = false;
```

The problem with this method is that for a split second the dialog shows up and then disappears. From a functional point of view it works fine, but it does annoy some users of my application and actually takes the "focus" away from the main form. I've also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
DialogForm myDialog = new DialogForm();
myDialog.Visible = false;
myDialog.Show();
```

There has to be a way to create the dialog and run it in the background without having to call "Show()." Thanks for any possible help!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This *really* sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).. Can you explain what problem you want to solve by doing this?

Comment: The dialog is actually doing work in the background. Much like a multiple thread application. I wish for the dialog to be created and do work but not be visible to the user unless the user wishes to see the dialog.

Comment: You should extract the work that needs to be done somewhere else and show the dialog at the right time.

Comment: Then the work shouldn't be in the dialog but be done before showing the dialog.

Comment: There is only one UI thread per application, no matter how many forms you have. If the form is doing work "in the background" and just calling `Application.DoEvents` every so often, your main form's performance will suffer. Could you use a `BackgroundWorker` for the background processing?

Comment: ...put the logic into a separate class and fire that off. Have the dialog query that class when the user decides to open it.

Comment: Quite related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921/load-a-form-without-showing-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like positioning the pop-up window in the left lower corner of the screen?
So even if it's showing for a split second, nobody will still be able to see it.

So before showing your window, write a line such as:

```
myDialog.Location = new Point(x,y);
// the x,y will be your coordinates of the lower-left margin of Form1
```

Comment: Given how clear it is that this is an XY-problem, I don’t think you should provide a solution to what OP is trying to do to solve a completely different problem. You should rather provide a solution to the actual problem instead (e.g. using a separate thread).