# How to invoke into message loop after Application.Run()

Tags: c#, winforms, message-loop

How can I invoke into the message loop of the tread/form after calling `Application.Run()` without a dialog? The reason is that I want to prepare (and later show) a dialog that is clickable even if a modal dialog is shown in the main application.

```
static Form1 dialog;

private static void CreateDialog(object obj)
{
    dialog = new Form1();
    Application.Run();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = new Thread(CreateDialog);
    thread.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);    //only for demonstration

    dialog.Invoke((Action)dialog.Show);    //InvalidOperationException: need window handle first
}
```

Comment: Don't create multiple UI threads.  You're just setting yourself up for failure.  Maintain a single UI thread and a single message loop.

Comment: Modal dialog is evil! Don't use it.

Comment: Unless you are a UX expert, stick to convention. The point of a modal dialog is that it blocks events to other parts of the UI. If you don't want this behavior, you don't want a modal dialog. Perhaps you need a non-modal dialog with the [TopMost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=net-5.0) property set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379459/how-to-invoke-ui-thread-in-winform-application-without-a-form-or-control

Comment: @Loathing Thanks for the link. This points me to a solution, although I have to admit it's more boylerplate code than I expected and still leaves to me the question what is the purpose of `Application.Run()` when you have seemingly no possibility to invoke code in this context...

Comment: @Servy Why shouldn't there be multiple UI threads? Can you please give me any reason except for "nobody does it" (which I don't think it's true).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I have no influence on it. I simply cannot rewrite the complete app and there are modal dialogs - but there are cases where a error message appears TopMost in front of a modal dialog but cannot be clicked away. This I want to avoid by having the error message in it's own thread so it can always be clicked away.

Comment: @LionAM You shouldn't have multiple UI threads because the underlying framework that you're using assumes there is only one, and is coded accordingly.  I didn't say "nobody does it", I said you shouldn't do it, because people that do do it are virtually always adding bugs to their program when they do, and are almost always greatly increasing the complexity of their programs.  Whatever problem you think requires multiple UI threads to solve should be solved using a single UI thread.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, but I don't agree. The framework has the ability to use multiple UI threads - you only have to ensure to access members of a form only from the thread where it's message loop runs. Also, threading always poses risk to bugs that you don't have in a single threaded app - but they still are a very useful tool. Also, my code above is not very complex - so how should it greatly increase the complexity?

Comment: @LionAM But you're not going to be writing all of the code marshalling to the UI thread.   There will be times you'll call into framework code that will marshal to the UI thread, expecting there to be only one.  I didn't say you shouldn't use multiple threads, I said you shouldn't make multiple *UI* threads.  Big difference.  You say your code isn't complex and yet *it doesn't work*, and you're trying to do all of this (unsuccessfully thus far) to get around the fact that you're creating a modal dialog that shouldn't be modal.  If you just used a non-modal dialog it would be *much* simpler.

Comment: @Servy As I wrote above, I cannot change the whole application. There are lot's of modal dialogs, but I only need an error message box to be clickable even if a modal dialog is open. Why do you think that "all of the code" has to invoke into the UI thread? The error dialog is opened from *one* central function (and closed from inside). The fact that the code does not work yet is absolutely no prove that it is complex or the completely wrong.

Comment: @LionAM I never said "all of the code has to invoke in the UI thread".  I said you shouldn't have multiple UI threads.  Your argument that your "simple" code that's *already* more complex than simply using the proper mechanism for your dialogs given the behavior that you want is preferable, despite *it not actually working* just makes no sense.  Comparing the complexity of different solutions to a problem is only meaningful *when they both work*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236448/discussion-between-lionam-and-servy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411493/1520078
I just have to access the `Handle` property of the Form to be able to invoke it from now on.

```
private static void CreateDialog(object obj)
{
    dialog = new Form1();
    _ = dialog.Handle;
    Application.Run();
}
```

Now this does not throw any more:

```
dialog.Invoke((Action)dialog.Show);
```